# How to query the video ram size of a ATI card on Linux?

Tags: linux, video-memory, ati

I want to know the physical video ram size in my application. I can get the same information of Nvidia card by using "nvidia-settings -q -t VideoRam".

I can use amdcccle to find this information, but it's an GUI app, so can't be used in my application. I wonder if there is a way to get this by command, function, or config file?

I'm using RHEL 5.4.

Hi, I can't get any information about my video card through dmidecode.

The output of lspci:

40:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Unknown device 68d8 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

```
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Unknown device e151
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at d0000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint IRQ 0
    Capabilities: [a0] Message Signalled Interrupts: 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [100] Unknown (11)
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
```

But my card have 1G video Ram on it, so the result here seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Untested for now, but parsing the output from [querying](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) `dmidecode` may yield the results you are looking for.

Another option would be [parsing the output](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/) of `lspci`.